# Are Azure container instances made for running simple command with simple output?

Tags: azure, docker, containers

i am trying to make use of Azure Instances and i need some explanation about the service itself.

I want to use ACI to launch the docker running a command prompting the output of the command and stop the docker.

**Is ACI the good service for that kind of things ?**

The Docker file look like this.

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add ffmpeg
CMD ffprobe -show_streams -show_format -loglevel warning -v quiet -print_format json /input.video
```

The docker run command to make it work look like this
`docker run --name ffprobe-docker -i -v /path/test.ts:/input.video --rm 72e84b2825af`

The issue ?

- I am not able to launch my script like i can make it work on my machine on azure

What i have done?

1. I created a private registery where i uploaded my Image.
2. I ran `az container create`command witch created the ressource

Now i don't know what to do next in order to make it work as expected?
because the container is terminated and the `az container exec --exec-command` is not showing anything on the terminal once the command is ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ACI, you can create it from your own Docker image in the ACR or other Registries. You can also run the command in it. But you should pay attention to that you cannot run the Docker command in it, because you can not nest container in it. It cannot be a Docker server. It just can be a container.

If you use the CLI command `az container exec --exec-command` then it will like this:

[image]

And the command as the `--exec-command` parameter should a bash command that can run in your Docker image.

I think the biggest advantage of ACI is the fastest and simplest, and without having to manage any virtual machines and without having to adopt a higher-level service.

Hope this will help you. Any more question please give me the message.

Comment: Okay, i understand.
I have two questions left: 

1: How should i modify my dockerfile to make my container live in order to make my az container exec ?

2: My docker will be use often, so Is it better to delete the container and re-create it after or should i do a start/stop routine ?

Comment: 1. You can always execute the command if your ACI is in the running state. If your docker image can work well then it can also work well as ACI. 2. I think re-create and stop is the same. Because when you stop the container then it will terminate, and it means delete. So just stop it. You can see [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/) to know how does it cost.

Comment: @Rolljee Any more question? I will try my best to help you if I can. Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: No i don't have any more question, i was out for the weekend, thx you for your time and explanations, it has been helpful. I managed to make it work by adding a command to make the docker waiting for my command then it execute correctly.